# Is it possible to transfer a ML model from R into ONNX format

Tags: r, machine-learning, onnx, mlr3

I am currently training a ML model in R (specifically using the `mlr3` framework - if this is a no-go I would be open to using other packages also). Later I want to apply the model into production, but for this it needs to be in ONNX format. My online research did not jet yield any possible solution on converting any ML model trained in R into ONNX format. Is this at all possible?

Comment: You might be able to get this to work with the onnx-r package: https://github.com/onnx/onnx-r